# How to use fonts from Fontello.com as html elements?

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome, fontello

I would like to use a few Font Awesome icons, so I have selected them on www.fontello.com, I have changed prefix to `fa-` and `font-family: 'fontello'` to  `font-family: 'FontAwesome'` and I have adjusted paths. 
Is there anything else I need to do?

When I use icon with pseudoelement it works

```
.sb-icon-search {
        font-family: 'FontAwesome';
        background: #fff;
        &:before {
            content: "\f002";
        }
    }
```

But when I want to use icons like this it doesn't work

```
 <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

This is part of my fonts.scss

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('assets/fonts/fontello.eot?86494570');
  src: url('assets/fonts/fontello.eot?86494570#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('assets/fonts/fontello.woff2?86494570') format('woff2'),
       url('assets/fonts/fontello.woff?86494570') format('woff'),
       url('assets/fonts/fontello.ttf?86494570') format('truetype'),
       url('assets/fonts/fontello.svg?86494570#fontello') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

 [class^="fa-"]:before, [class*=" fa-"]:before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.fa-location:before { content: '\e800'; }
.fa-phone:before { content: '\e801'; }
.fa-mail:before { content: '\e802'; }
```

Comment: Why don't you downlaod fonticons from fontawesome.io itself if you are using only  fontawesome specifically.

Comment: I only want to pick a few icons, not whole set

Comment: I get it, then why don't you use the fontello file intact? It should be working btw.